# Project different embedded structures to same name

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I am writing a python script that performs these tasks:

- Query a MongoDB Collection with embeded documents
- Aggregate and Project to change the field names that are returned in the query to match a "u_" convention
- Import the values to ServiceNow via REST API

**ISSUE:**

The embedded documents are not in a consistent structure. The HOSTNAME field is stored in varying structures.

I need to return the hostname as u_hostname. I need the value of $hostnames.name if it exists OR the value of $hostname if it exists.

How can I determine if either one exists, and return it as u_hostname?

**Structure 1  Hostname stored as $hostnames.name**

```
{
    "_id" : "192.168.1.1",
    "addresses" : {
        "ipv4" : "192.168.1.1"
    },
    "hostnames" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "PTR",
            "name" : "example.hostname.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Structure 2  Hostname stored as $hostname**

```
{
    "_id" : "192.168.2.1",
    "addresses" : {
        "ipv4" : "192.168.2.1"
    },
    "hostname" : "helloworld.com",

}
```

**Script:**

The query will only return the value of $hostname, not $hostname.name.

```
cmp = db['computers'].aggregate([
        {"$project" : {
                "_id":0,
                "u_hostname": "$hostnames.name",
                "u_hostname": "$hostname",
                "u_ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4"
        }}
])
```

Comment: Is "hostnames" one element array?

Comment: Not sure if I am understanding properly, but I think "hostnames" is an array of objects. As you can see in Structure 1 the "hostnames" array contains two properties "name" and "type".

Comment: Do you always have one object in the array?

Comment: Yes I think so. I do not see any instances where $hostnames.name contains multiple values.

Comment: The version is MongoDB 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project) the "hostname" field.

```
cmp = db['computers'].aggregate([
    {"$project": { 
        "u_hostname": {
            "$ifNull": [
                "$hostnames.name", 
                { "$map": { 
                    "input": {"$literal": ["A"]}, 
                    "as": "el", 
                    "in": "$hostname"
                }}
            ]
        }, 
        "_id": 0, 
        "u_ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4"
    }},
    {"$unwind": "$u_hostname"}
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the $unwind, $group and $setUnion operators included in the aggregate function. It will allow you to flatten you list of hostnames.name and then union them with the other hostnames.