# Workaround for preserveNullAndEmptyArrays in MongoDB 2.6

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using a Python script to query a MongoDB collection. The collection contains embedded documents with varying structures.

I am trying to simply "$unwind" an array contained in several documents. However, the array is not in ALL documents.

That means only the documents that contain the field are returned, the others are ignored. I am using PyMongo 2.6 so I am unable to use `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) because it is new in MongoDB 3.2

Is there a workaround to this? Something along the lines of "if the field path exists, unwind".

The structure of documents and code in question is outlined in detail in this separate but [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234053/project-different-embedded-structures-to-same-name) I asked earlier.

**ISSUE:**

I am trying to "$unwind" the value of `$hostnames.name`. However, since the path doesn't exist in all documents, this results in several ignored documents.

**Structure 1 Hostname stored as $hostnames.name**

```
{
    "_id" : "192.168.1.1",
    "addresses" : {
        "ipv4" : "192.168.1.1"
    },
    "hostnames" : [ 
        {
            "type" : "PTR",
            "name" : "example.hostname.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Structure 2 Hostname stored as $hostname**

```
{
    "_id" : "192.168.2.1",
    "addresses" : {
        "ipv4" : "192.168.2.1"
    },
    "hostname" : "helloworld.com",

}
```

**Script**

```
cmp = db['computers'].aggregate([
    {"$project": { 
        "u_hostname": {
            "$ifNull": [
                "$hostnames.name", 
                { "$map": { 
                    "input": {"$literal": ["A"]}, 
                    "as": "el", 
                    "in": "$hostname"
                }}
            ]
        }, 
        "_id": 0, 
        "u_ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4"
    }},
    {"$unwind": "$u_hostname"}
])
```

I am missing all documents that have an empty array for "hostnames".

Here is the structure of the documents that are still missing.

**Structure 3**

```
{
   "_id" : "192.168.1.1",
    "addresses" : { "ipv4" : "192.168.1.1" },
    "hostnames" : [], }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can still preserve all the documents where the array field is missing by playing with the [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator and use a logical [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)ition processing to assign a value to the newly computed field.

The condition here is [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) which returns True if the field is `[None]` or False when the condition expression evaluates to false.

```
cmp = db['computers'].aggregate(
    [
        {"$project":{ 
            "u_ipv4": "$addresses.ipv4",
            "u_hostname": {
                "$let": {
                    "vars": {
                        "hostnameName": {
                            "$cond": [
                                {"$eq": ["$hostnames", []]},
                                [None], 
                                {"$ifNull": ["$hostnames.name", [None]]}
                            ]
                        }, 
                        "hostname": {"$ifNull": ["$hostname", None]}
                    }, 
                    "in": {
                        "$cond": [ 
                            {"$eq": ["$$hostnameName", [None]]}, 
                            {"$map": {
                                "input": {"$literal": [None]}, 
                                "as": "el", 
                                "in": "$$hostname"
                            }}, 
                            "$$hostnameName"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }},        
        { "$unwind": "$u_hostname" }
    ]
)
```